# Using Cancan authorization on a child model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using CanCanCan and I'm trying to forbid a User from accessing other users's galleries, but cannot figure out the right way to do it in the Ability class.

User has_one Profile

Profile has_one Gallery

```
  def user_abilities(user)
    can :read, Profile

    can [:edit, :update], Profile, user_id: user.id
    can [:edit, :update], Gallery, user_id: user.id # also tried gallery: { user_id: user.id }, profile_id: user.profile.id and so on

  end
```

It seems to me that I have (unsuccessfully) tried all of the advice I could find on StackOverflow.

Comment: what is the issue with `can [:edit, :update], Gallery , profile_id: user.profile.id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK solved it myself after carefully reading the docs

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource :profile
  load_and_authorize_resource :gallery, through: :profile, singleton: true
```